# Что хуже, бесконечные таймеры или промисы?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос по работе движка! Что хуже? Бесконечные таймеры или промисы? И почему? Такой вопрос задали на собеседовании. Кто может пояснить?

Comment: таймеры это setTimeout?

Comment: Думаю, тут [хорошо объяснено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752620/promise-vs-settimeout)

Comment: Думаю, таймер не имеет никакого отношения к промису. Запрос XmlHttpRequest просто бывает синхронный и асинхронный. Синхронный уже в прошлом. Возможно кто-то проверяет таймером выполнился ли запрос, но думаю что и для случая с промисом можно начудить создав таймер.

Comment: @nick_n_a, поясните, причем тут XmlHttpRequest ?

Comment: XmlHttpRequest  - аналог промиса, и... возможно таймер нужен для него. Таймером ведь невозможно сделать то что делает промис, поэтому первое что приходит  в голову что промис нельзя заменить чисто таймером. Наверное вопрос чем таймаут отличается от промиса.

Comment: @nick_n_a вы путаете промисы и fetch

Comment: как я понял, таймер это макротаск а промис микро. И в самом web api есть две очереди, одна для макротасков, другая для микро. Причем микротаски имеют приоритет перед  макротасками. Только не могу понять почему бесконечные макротасками опаснее чем микротаски.

Comment: @RevOiT а где написано про это?То есть про то что один микротаск а другой макро?

Comment: Избыток Сусликов [Вот например](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).

Comment: Перевод https://habr.com/ru/post/264993/

Comment: Ответ на данный вопрос https://habr.com/ru/post/461401/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить про бесконечность, то ответ - хуже `Promise`.

Особенность микротасок в том, что они выполняются в первую очередь после окончания текущей таски, пока не очистится собственная очередь микротасок. Таким образом, если микротаска создает микротаску и так до бесконечности, то это полностью заблокирует `event loop`.

В свою очередь бесконечный нулевой таймер (интервал, скорее) создает таску в конец текущей очереди. Если очередь пуста, то код в таймере выполнится сразу. Если очередь имеет задания, то выполнятся сначала они, а потом ваш `timer-callback`.

```
const int0 = setInterval(() => console.log('interval 0'))
const int10 = setInterval(() => console.log('interval 10'))

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(int0);
  clearInterval(int10);
  console.log('Если бы код был заблокирован интервалами, мы бы не смогли вызвать эту функцию');
}, 200);
```

Ни один интервал не блокирует выполнение другого асинхронного кода полностью. Основная очередь пополняется последовательно то одним, то другим (в случае других значений `timeout` картина была бы другой, но смысл то же).

```
function infinitePromise() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        console.log('Бесконечный промис');
        res();
    }).then(() => infinitePromise());
}

setTimeout(() => console.log('Этот код никогда не выполнится'), 200);
infinitePromise();
```

В этом случае очередь микротасок никогда не очистится и `setTimeout` не сможет поставить задание в очередь.

Термины, типа `хуже/лучше` немного странные в этом случае. Но если конкретно про возможность браузерного движка дышать между выполнением вашего кода, то `setInterval` - больше похоже на нормальное сердцебиение. Promise - это смерть от таскоизлияния.